# Which regression model to use for binary variables (independent variables having 0/1 values)?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, random-forest

I am working with a dataset which has binary variables but my dependent variable is continuous. Which regression model can I use here to train and predict given those binary variables? I am not sure if I can use Multiple Regression or Random Forest.

Answer (score 4):

You could use multiple regression or random forest or both.  Which will work best will depend a lot on your data and the associations among them.